# Multiple ENTRYPOINT for running binaries

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am setting up a Dockerfile for one of my third-party application and I would like to setup multiple entrypoints to two different binaries from the thirdparty application. Is there a way to configure it?
I looked at few examples and all of them suggest to wrap it in a shell script. but it doesn't really work for me as these two binaries have different functionalities and take different arguments. is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: I don't see why a shell script would not work. You can process all the parameters you give on the docker run command in the script and do whatever you like depending on them.

Comment: Do they run sequentially, or in parallel?  If in parallel you'd generally want to run multiple containers, and you could have multiple almost-identical images that differ except for their default `CMD`.